# GCS max number of inserts per second

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am consuming events from Kafka and writing them directly into a bucket in GCS in a Java application. Each event is written in path `bucketName/categoryId(random UUID)/eventId(random UUID)` where each category contains up to 500 events and they are written more or less close to each other in time. The method I am using to insert the events is:

```
storage.create(blobinfo, compressedData, doesNotExist());
```

The request rate I am getting is 6 event/second measured on the writing method with micrometer, while [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#ramp-up) says that GCS can handle around 1000 events/second. I have other identical consumers writing to Postgres the same info reaching around 100 event/seconds.

Both the computing pod (eu-west-1) and the bucket (multi regional) are located in EU zone in GCP infrastructure.

Is there something that can be done to speed this use case up even more?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, be sure that the rate at which you're handling events is actually gated by GCS and not the rest of your compute infrastructure.  Try leaving out the write to GCS and see what the performance is like.  You didn't say exactly how you are benchmarking, so it's kind of hard to accept in general what you're stating. Ideally your question includes enough information that anyone can use to duplicate the results exactly as you observe them.

After that (and without seeing any more details other than what you're showing), the first thing is to move your compute closer to your data.  This means changing the region of your GCS bucket to be closer to your compute, or the other way around.  Every write incurs at least 1 full round trip with the bucket, and you will want to minimize the distance covered in that.

You should also consider what you can do to parallelize the writes within your compute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added more clarifications on my question about how I am running the consumer.